# MYSQLi Select statement - not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Someone please help me with the reason as to why this is not working. i am checking if a record exists with count. if it exits no add new, if it does not add new allowed.

```
<?php
// Setting a value for the new week to be added
$TeamOwner = $teams->MemberID->CurrentValue;
$OldWeek = $teams->WeekID->CurrentValue;
$NewWeek = ($OldWeek+1);
echo $NewWeek;
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","soccer_team");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
      throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
      getPosts($con); "Please try again later: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM teams WHERE MemberID= $TeamOwner AND WeekID= $NewWeek");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $row = $result->fetch_row();
     $total = $row[0];
     echo "No of Teams created this week: " . $total;
    mysqli_close($con);
} 
 switch ($total)
 {
   case ($total== 0):
   ?><script> document.getElementById('btnAction').disabled = true; </script><?php
   break;
   case ($total == 1): 
   echo 'You cannot create another team, please update your existing team';  
   break;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Why using both `OO` & `Procedural` style `mysqli_fetch_array` & `fetch_row` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching from you result set twice:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
```

You need to remove one of these.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe change the start to MemberID AND add "as c".

```
SELECT COUNT(MemberID) as c FROM teams WHERE MemberID= $TeamOwner AND WeekID= $NewWeek"
```